# UN50RU7100FXZA share USB drive over network?

Tags: networking, usb, hard-drive, lubuntu, smart-tv

I have a Lubuntu desktop and a Samsung [UN50RU7100FXZA](https://www.samsung.com/us/televisions-home-theater/tvs/uhd-tvs/50--class-ru7100-smart-4k-uhd-tv--2019--un50ru7100fxza/) SmartTV, both connected to the same local network (WiFi router).

The SmartTV has an external HDD connected to it via USB to play movies directly off of the HDD. This works fine, but currently the only method I have of adding movies to the HDD is by disconnecting it from the TV and physically moving it to the computer, copying the files, then moving it back to the TV.

Is there some way to avoid having to physically disconnect/reconnect it? Preferably by having the SmartTV share the HDD's contents with the Linux desktop (so I can manipulate the files using the computer)?

Comment: You would have to check with the manufacturer of the TV if you can access the TV itself through the network.   Some Smart TVs can browse your network so you could share your videos that way, or look into something like Plex that is a server / client app that a lot of Smart TVs can install

Comment: Samsung support can be reached at https://www.samsung.com/us/support/order-help/ by clicking on Live Chat, so you may ask them if a USB-connected HDD can be shared by the UN50RU7100FXZA  - but have you considered sharing the drive from your Lubuntu PC to the Samsung instead?

Comment: I want the TV to be able to work separate from the network and the PC, except for the purpose of transferring files.

Comment: This question seems off-topic to me (the question is all about the TV becoming a file server so it can be remotely operated, or enabling `ssh` on TV so as to `scp` files to the TV connected hdd).  You gave no details as to your Lubuntu (legacy or modern?) so we don't know your desktop anyway, however to me it's off-topic - https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible with your TV. I have a similar Samsung TV (different family but same model line), and there is no support to mount or browse a network attached storage drive.

However, the TV does include a basic web browser that can stream media. So you could move the HDD to your Linux box, the set up Plex or another free media streamer. You could then use your Samsung TVs browser to connect to something like 192.168.0.10. Plex would serve a homepage showing the available movies, which can include sources like external hard drives.

Depending on how far the TV is fro the router, you will probably want a hardwired connection of the movies are 4K.